Maven JavaDoc Plugin doesn't respect language preference
I've set up Maven JavaDoc Plugin to convert my JavaDoc comments into a static HTML site. However, the site generated is in German even though I've set the language preference to English. Note that my system's language is German. See https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html#locale
How to get an English version of the JavaDoc static site?
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <sourcepath>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/delombok</sourcepath>
        <locale>en_US</locale>
        <source>22</source>
        <show>private</show>
        <doclint>none</doclint>
        <tags>
            <tag>
                <name>apiNote</name>
                <placement>a</placement>
                <head>API Note:</head>
            </tag>
            <tag>
                <name>implNote</name>
                <placement>a</placement>
                <head>Implementation Note:</head>
            </tag>
        </tags>
        <doclet>nl.talsmasoftware.umldoclet.UMLDoclet</doclet>
        <docletArtifact>
            <groupId>nl.talsmasoftware</groupId>
            <artifactId>umldoclet</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
        </docletArtifact>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

Of course, I'm talking about the skeleton of the website, not the user-generated content.


ChatGPT made me aware of this work-around: Add <additionalJOptions>-J-Duser.language=en -J-Duser.country=US</additionalJOptions> to the <configuration> block of the plugin.
